# django custom timezone middleware causing django.contrib.humanize test to fail

Tags: python, django, timezone

The custom middleware below, when it is active, is causing this test to fail when I run `python manage.py test`.  We are running Django 1.5.4:

```
FAIL: test_naturalday_uses_localtime    (django.contrib.humanize.tests.HumanizeTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/endaga-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/humanize/tests.py", line 161, in test_naturalday_uses_localtime
    self.humanize_tester([dt], ['yesterday'], 'naturalday')
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/endaga-server/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/humanize/tests.py", line 47, in humanize_tester
    msg="%s test failed, produced '%s', should've produced '%s'" % (method, rendered, result))
AssertionError: naturalday test failed, produced 'today', should've produced 'yesterday'
```

the offending middleware:

```
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    """Activates django's timezone processing."""

    def process_request(self, request):
        """Intercedes during a request."""
        if not request.user:
            return
        try:
            user_profile = models.UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(user_profile.timezone))
        except models.UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            return
```

How can I modify this middleware such that the test does not fail?

Comment: I see 3 possibilities: 1. `TimezoneMiddleware` breaks some assumptions about how you should work with timezones in django -- fix the middleware 2. Or `test_naturalday_uses_localtime` assumes too much about timezones in the environment -- fix the test 3. The test is correct but `django.contrib.humanize` itself has a bug related to timezones -- fix the `humanize` module. It might be worth reporting the issue on a bug tracker for the corresponding projects.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't. You can mock it out during the test, or make sure the users timezone is the same as the timezone on which you run the tests.